# Multiple ImageButtons with setOnClickListener (clicks but does not launch activities)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, onclicklistener, imagebutton

I have managed to successfully start two activities using the ImageButton along with .setOnClickListener tied to it, i have also included layouts with different ImageButtons. Each button launches an activity. I have created the activities. I have also managed to remover crash bugs, lint errors, have the latest Android SDK. However now the buttons stop working even though you hear the click. Neither the activity launches on the first imageButton nor the second one.

This happens the moment i put multiple ImageButtons in. It works with 1 button. I suspect the (this) command in the class is confused as to what to call. My intent call method to start new activities are streamlined and basic for quick, uncomplicated access.

Can someone please help me as to why the multiple setOnclickListener cannot be tied to the relevant imageButtons please?

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
ImageButton imageButton1;
ImageButton imageButton2;
ImageButton imageButton3;
ImageButton imageButton4;
Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reusable_layout);
    imageButton1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    imageButton2=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    imageButton3=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    imageButton4=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);

    imageButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageButton3.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageButton4.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

public void onClick1(View view) {
    Intent intent = 
            new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
}
            public void onClick2(View view) {
                Intent intent = 
                new Intent(this,     OtherActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);          
}
```

If you notice I have only coded 2 of the four buttons (so once this code works in theory the others should).

This is what OtherActivity from imageButton1 calls.

```
package com.example.startanotheractivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class OtherActivity extends Activity
            implements OnClickListener {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.other_layout);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

and this is the activity imageButton2 calls

```
package com.example.startanotheractivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


public class OtherActivity2 extends Activity
        implements OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.other_layout_2);
Intent intent = getIntent();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Here is my layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="#FFFFFF" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="566dp"
        android:layout_height="456dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/gatanga1"
        android:onClick="onClick1" />

       <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="540dp"
        android:layout_height="189dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/gatanga2"
        android:onClick="onClick2" />

          <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="540dp"
        android:layout_height="189dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/gatanga3"
        android:onClick="onClick3" />

             <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="540dp"
        android:layout_height="189dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/gatanga4"
        android:onClick="onClick4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you

Many many thanks.

Comment: try below solution and let me know whether it is working or not?

Answer (score 0):

use a switch statement in onClick method

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

  switch(v.getId()){

  case R.id.imageButton1: /** Start a new Activity OtherActivity.java */
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyCards.class);
       this.startActivity(intent);
       break;

  case R.id.imageButton2:  /** Start a new Activity OtherActivity2.java */
       Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity2.class);
       this.startActivity(intent2);
       break;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The onClick method passes the clicked view as an variable, you can use a switch statement to determine which view was clicked and then you can perform your operations..

```
public void onClick(View v) {

  switch(v.getId()){

  case R.id.imageButton1:
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
       break;

  case R.id.imageButton2:
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity2.class);
       startActivity(intent2);
       break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scholars, Educated Aristocrats and of course Plumbers.

Thank you for replying. It works now by the code i did, although i will try the above solutions. I have experimented with switches and i do like them. I want to make sure memory management and file sizes are kept to a minimum as the end app will have about 40 activities.

However the way i did it was i removed all the other ImageButtons declarations in MainActivity except:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
ImageButton imageButton1;
Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.reusable_layout);
imageButton1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    }
```

The onClick methods then were left as onClick1,onClick2. Both activities worked. I added onClick3 and onClick4 like the below:

```
public void onClick1(View view) {
Intent intent = 
        new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}
        public void onClick2(View view) {
            Intent intent = 
            new Intent(this,     OtherActivity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);          
}
        public void onClick3(View view) {
            Intent intent = 
            new Intent(this, OtherActivity3.class);
            startActivity(intent);
}
        public void onClick4(View view) {
            Intent intent = 
            new Intent(this,     OtherActivity4.class);
            startActivity(intent);          
}
```

I think what seemed to happen then is the code wasnt confused or stuck in a loop (it didnt crash on my original posting). But instead now it goes straight to layout, gets the "onClick1" for button 1 and "onClick2" and matches them with the public void onClick(X) in MainActivity, because i have just declared i am using the ImageButton and an Intent, right after onClickListener, it works.

Note if i move around this code it breaks or will give me the same error. Regardless, i am happy it works but am intrigued as to why i did not have to declare all my buttons. Maybe it is just the logic in Java Code working.

I will definately try the switches and amendments later experimenting.

With best wishes.

Answer (score -1):

in the MainActivity you should correctly implement OnClickListener interface:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageButton1:
            Intent intent = 
            new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.imageButton2:
            Intent intent = 
            new Intent(this, OtherActivity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
     }
}
```